# accepts_nested_attributes_for called twice in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class StepQuiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :step
  has_many :step_quiz_questions, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :step
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :step_quiz_questions, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :step_id, :instructions, :correct_to_pass, :retakes_allowed, :time_limit, :step_attributes, :step_quiz_questions_attributes
end
```

Am I allowed to have accepts_nested_attributes_for called twice for a given model. It appears to work with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a class method defined here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

The answer is yes, so that you can tune every single case.